# Convert List<ScanResults> to ArrayList<HashMap<String>>

Tags: android, listview, arraylist, listadapter

I want to convert the Android WiFi scan results a `List<ScanResults>` to a `List<? extends Map<String, ?>>`

This is for use with the `SimpleAdapter` which I would like to use

I have tried converting scans to a `String[]` for each `BSSID` and `SSID` then adding them to an `ArrayList` with a loop, but was unable to do with without overriding each as I went.

Comment: What do you mean by overriding? I think your step is correct. Do a loop for the scan result and assign relevant values as the map key and value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put the scan result into a hash map. Here is what I did.

```
List<ScanResult> results = wifiMgr.getScanResults();
rssiList = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

for (ScanResult result : results) {
    rssiList.put(result.BSSID, result.level);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Am I able to put this into an `ArrayList` or other type of list I could use with a `SimpleAdapter`?

Comment: You can put the HashMap into an ArrayList like [this](http://ykyuen.wordpress.com/2010/01/03/android-simple-listview-using-simpleadapter/).